# C++ bitset in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, bitset, gpu-shared-memory

I have an existing C++ code that extensively uses the bitset template. I am porting this code to CUDA C, and I am really new to CUDA programming. Can I use the bitset template as a `__shared__` variable?

Comment: You need to implement this pattern yourself. Is `"shared" variable` mean variable in shared memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use the `bitset` container in CUDA at all, because there is no device implementation of it. It should be trivial to implement it in terms of a regular array though, and you can put the array in shared memory.

Comment: To others just showing up: be careful about writing to bits in an `unsigned char`, etc in parallel from multiple threads.  I'm guessing that writes from different threads to the same `unsigned char` can smash each other without using something like `atomicCAS(...)`.